# Are there easier ways to report about malfunctions experienced while using Ubuntu other than using particular bug trackers?

Tags: video, intel-graphics, xubuntu, bug-reporting

I use Xubuntu on a computer with an Intel 82852/82855GM video card and have a nasty problem with video playback: after some time of playback a video player screen comes just blue, and when I close it my screen is filled with garbage and the system hangs. The workaround I've found is using mplayer with -vo x11 to render it software. I understand (because the same case caused similar problem in Arch I used half a year ago, not just Ubuntu, and the problem never occurs when I use other window managers than XFWM) that this is probably a problem of the combination of My Intel card with XFWM. From this comes the problem - where to submit the bug - to XFCE bug tracker or to Intel one (which I even have no idea where to look for). At the same time I wouldn't like to register in those issue trackers just to use them once. So I am not straight about submitting the bug, but can explain clearly how to reproduce it, which, I believe can itself still be a useful contribution to the community.

So, is there a way to submit a bug I've experienced without complications, for better-qualified specialists to review it and put into corresponding issue trackers themselves if they aren't there yet?

Answer (score 6):

We really encourage you to [use the bug tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Reporting) even if you aren't sure which package(s) the symptoms affect. [A dedicated team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad) will triage your bug report and assist in engaging the relevant upstream developers so that an appropriate fix can be developed, tested, and made available in an Ubuntu release.

Comment: We even encourage you to report any bugs to launchpad so the developers can determine if the bug is caused by Xubuntu before it goes upstream.